# How to stop the systems music? (VK_MEDIA_STOP not working everywhere)

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am developing an application which runs in the background, and when a specific event is happening, the music which is played by media players should be stopped.

The major music players like Spotify and Windows Media Player support being controlled via special keyboard keys "Stop", "Start", "Next track" etc.

So I would like to use this feature to control all running media players and tell them to stop playing.

Media players which do not implement these keys won't be targeted by my application; they will be incompatible.

Currently, I have following function, which works so far:

```
procedure StopMusic;
const
  KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
begin
  keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
  keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;
```

I don't know exactly how this mechanism works. The operating system messages all applications, no matter in which application I am currently working in, but only if keybd_event is called. (SendMessage WM_KEYDOWN won't work)

The problem I am having is that some applications like OwnCloud swallow these keys if their window is focused (also if pressed on a real keyboard). I will contact them to report this bug. But in the meantime I want to try to make a workaround for it.

My idea for a workaround is to quickly switch the focus to a different window, then perform the virtual key press, then switch back to the window which was active:

```
procedure StopMusic;
const
  KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
var
  hBak: HWND;
begin
  hBak := GetForegroundWindow();
  try
    SetForegroundWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  finally
    SetForegroundWindow(hBak);
  end;
end;
```

But this function does not work at all. It has no effect, no matter which Window is currently focused. I guess it is because the Desktop can't gain the focus.

*Therefore my question is:*

- Which workaround can I do? (Beside asking OwnCloud to fix that bug)
- Or is there a completely different strategy / API possibility to tell the media players to stop playing?

**UPDATE: Solution 1 (Dirty)**

The first workaround is to switch the focus to the taskbar. But obviously, this is a dirty solution, since it is an implementation detail of Windows.

```
procedure StopMusic;
const
  KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
var
  hBak: HWND;
begin
  hBak := GetForegroundWindow();
  try
    SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil));
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  finally
    SetForegroundWindow(hBak);
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE: Solution 2 (Dirty)**

This solution also works. It is not a hardcoded string like Shell_TrayWnd, but still using an undocumented API call.

```
function TaskmanWindow: HWND;
type
  TGetTaskmanWindow = function(): HWND; stdcall;
var
  hUser32: THandle;
  GetTaskmanWindow: TGetTaskmanWindow;
begin
  Result := 0;
  hUser32 := GetModuleHandle('user32.dll');
  if (hUser32 > 0) then
  begin
    @GetTaskmanWindow := GetProcAddress(hUser32, 'GetTaskmanWindow'); // Undocumented
    if Assigned(GetTaskmanWindow) then
    begin
      Result := GetTaskmanWindow;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure StopMusic;
const
  KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0;
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
var
  hBak: HWND;
begin
  hBak := GetForegroundWindow();
  try
    SetForegroundWindow(TaskmanWindow);
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  finally
    SetForegroundWindow(hBak);
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE: Solution 3 (Good)**

The clean solution of the problem is to send an AppCommand to all applications

```
procedure StopMusic;
begin
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, MAKELONG(0, APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP));
end;
```

**UPDATE: Bugreport**

A friend with an github account posted [the bugreport](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/5439) for me.

Comment: AutoHotKey will get it done. Don't ever use keybd_event though. Read its documentation to learn why not.

Comment: It's in application's discretion whether to honor the keys or not. If it doesn't respond to the real keyboard when it's in the foreground, no input generation will make it do so.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes; this is why I wanted to switch to a window where I know that it accepts the keys.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This means that I need to call AutoHotKey with my Delphi program. And after all, AutoHotKey can't do anything which I can't do with the WinApi directly, I guess.

Comment: I don't understand, how can an arbitrary window of a program stop media that's playing on another program?

Comment: Why do you tweak the foreground window anyway? Seems a little pointless. Anyway I'm voting to close because you are asking us to solve an ill defined problem. You want us to tell you how to automate arbitrary programs. That's way too broad.

Comment: That's not too broad. I think you simply didn't understand the problem.  I have a very clear problem: I want to make music stop playing. And since some windows swallow the keys, I want to send the key to a different window. Sertac Akyuz: I don't know how this works. If I press that key on my keyboard (or send the VK), media-applications like WMP or Spotify will stop playing. After all, that's what this keyboard key is used for: When people are working e.g. in Microsoft Office and don't want to switch windows. I assume that VK_MEDIA_STOP has a special meaning in the Windows operating system.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think so. If it was master mute or master volume adjustment that would be true. The OS can't control third party programs. Suppose you're playing media across several programs and at the same time the OS is playing incoming message. Which one is supposed to stop?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't know. The message somehow reaches every application. Just out of curiosity, I have setup following:  I opened Spotify, playing music and opened WMP not playing music.  Then I focused Microsoft Word. When I press the "Start/Stop" Key on my keyboard, Spotify stops and WMP starts. When I press again, WMP stops and Spotify starts playing. So, it is likely that Windows called all applications, but only if the windows where I am at (e.g. Microsoft Word) didn't swallow the VK.    PS: Also, it seems like VK_MEDIA_STOP only has effect with `keybd_event`, but not with `SendMessage`.

Comment: There's no point in fiddling with the foreground window. Your application in the foreground is quite fine. Read remarks in `WM_APPCOMMAND`'s documentation. If your application doesn't *swallow* the key, the default window procedure will generate a shell hook event (`HSHELL_APPCOMMAND`) and interested applications (`RegisterShellHookWindow`) can then respond. Non-interested applications will do nothing.

Comment: For those application's that's a problem - when in the foreground that *swallow's the command - , you could write an application that registers for raw input for instance and then calls the default window procedure to hand the command to the shell. But that's obviously beyond the scope of this question, since to run the code in the question your application must be in the foreground.

Comment: @DanielMarschall: apps like Windows Media Player and Spotify are *specifically coded* to recognize the keyboard's media keys, whereas apps like ownCloud are clearly *NOT*. This is an *optional* feature. Nothing you do in *your* code with change that fact. You should contact the ownCloud author and submit a feature request. In the meantime, your only option in this situation is to issue `VK_MEDIA_STOP` for apps that support it, and also look for ownCloud's UI specifically (and other affected apps you choose to detect) and manipulate it directly. That takes extra research and coding to setup

Comment: @SertacAkyuz  That's interesting. So, did I correctly understand: If I press that key on my keyboard, or if I send a keybd_event VK_MEDIA_STOP , then Windows will send APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP to all applications, except if the application which is currently active, "catches" that event?
So, every normal application would pass this event to the operating system, while OwnCloud (which has this bug) doesn't do so?
I wonder, can I directly call all applications and request the media-stop-command? I tried `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP);` , but it doesn't work.

Comment: If it's not too broad, please make it about a single program that you wish to automate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Directly communicating with a specific program like Spotify or WMP would be the wrong solution. I would like to use Windows built-in support for stopping media. There are API functions available, which do actually work, and this thread is asking for a workaround or alternative strategy, because a specific application is blocking them. (I have also updated my question)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I found the solution!! `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, MAKELONG(0, APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP));`  Thank you so much for your hint about `WM_APPCOMMAND` . If you like, please add an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Daniel, you're welcome. You go ahead please. Obviously I lost it somewhere, if owncloud would be responding to wm_appcommands it would do so to the keyboard I'd think.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I do understand that sending the WM_APPCOMMAND to each application (using the broadcast) will work, but I do not understand how this bug in OwnCloud can happen, or why Windows fails to spread the AppCommand to the other applications when the OwnCloud window is focused. I thought you know under which circumstances Windows broadcasts WM_APPCOMMAND to all applications?

Comment: Nope. I know nothing about the OS broadcasting a WM_APPCOMMAND. I don't believe it does.

Comment: The simple to the question here is that it is not possible to automate all music players with the same method. But you don't want to do it for all players. It's just one. If you asked about that player it would be a valid question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "it is not possible to automate all music players with the same method. " --> it is possible, via the Windows built-in media appcommands/virtualkeys. " It's just one" --> no. i want to reach all, WMP, Spotify, whatever. (Windows does that with the appcommand broadcast). Not sure why you think I am asking about a single player.

Comment: The answer is as I said then. It can't be done.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the consequence in the bug report is slightly off, no WM_APPCOMMAND is expected to reach other media players. The program's window is expected to call its window procedure with the message after it has handled the message as it wishes, so that the shell event is generated. I think the writer of the application will have no problem understanding the issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
> keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_STOP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
> ...
> ```
>
> *I don't know exactly how this mechanism works...*

This code simulates pressing the `VK_MEDIA_STOP` key which generates a `WM_APPCOMMAND` message with the `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP` application command. It's possible to learn what happens then from the message's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If a child window does not process this message and instead calls
>   **DefWindowProc**, **DefWindowProc** will send the message to its parent
>   window. If a top level window does not process this message and
>   instead calls **DefWindowProc**, **DefWindowProc** will call a shell hook with
>   the hook code equal to **HSHELL_APPCOMMAND**.

So, when a window of an application is in the foreground when you press the key, or simulate the input, if the focused control or its parent chain does not halt the processing of the message and the top level window calls the default window procedure, then a shell event is generated. The well behaving media players you mention are the ones that have [registered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644989(v=vs.85).aspx) to receive shell hook messages. This mechanism is also explained in this MSDN [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140929-00/?p=43963).

What OwnCloud does is to, obviously, not calling the default window procedure after it receives a `WM_APPCOMMAND`. When it is in the foreground this happens to cause your problem; other media applications cannot respond to the message since no shell event is generated.

Hence, your workaround of trying to activate a non-interfering window and generating keyboard input to that window. This is pointless, your own application's window is as good as the taskbar's or any other application's window as long as you don't do anything with the message. When your application's window is in the foreground and you generate input, if Windows Media Player is not responding, there is something else and we'd need a reproduction case for that.

In any case, generating a shell event will not be helpful to OwnCloud or similar applications since they don't have a registered window for shell hook notifications. To these applications, you can send the `WM_APPCOMMAND` yourself. The linked MSDN blog post has an example of doing that. Although not suggested, you can also broadcast the message if you have a possibility of running an indefinite number of media applications. For a number of considerations why this is not suggested, see this MSDN [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060613-05/?p=30893/). If you don't see any problem broadcasting the message, consider using `SendMessageTimeout` instead of `SendMessage`.